# Android Canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, left, top, paint) after rotation

Tags: android, rotation, android-canvas

Is there a detailed documentation explaining the left/top parameter used in the canvas.drawBitmap method?

I thought it should always be the position relative to left-top corner of the canvas. For example, if I want to draw something at the top left corner, I just draw from origin (0,0).

However, I found this is not the case if the canvas is rotated 90 degree.

```
canvas.save();
canvas.rotate(90, canvas.getWidth()/2, canvas.getHeight()/2);
canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, null);
canvas.restore();
```

I was expecting the bitmap should be drawn from the left top corner on the rotated canvas, and displayed from right top corner after I restore the canvas, but it comes out different result.

I have to draw at

```
x= (canvas.getWidth()-canvas.getHeight())/2 
y= (canvas.getHeight()-canvas.getWidth())/2
```

to get the expected result, why?